# How to get a random list value from a php array

Tags: php, arrays, random

How can I get random values from an array with the PHP `list` function. Normally I have this which just give me the 3 first values in the array:

```
list($first, $second, $third) = $array;
```

But I want to get a random value so I did this but I get no error and also no value:

```
list($first, $second, $third) = array_rand($array);
```

Please anyone with a clue on how I can achieve this? I want to get only 3 random values from the array

Comment: `shuffle()` the array before it.

Comment: Like this `shuffle($array);`?

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE Yes. It isn't hard to look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `shuffle()` the array.

```
shuffle ($array);
list($first, $second, $third) = $array;
```

Comment: That looks like the easiest way to do it. array_rand just returns a random key/index from the array (which would explain why you got nothing back). Why are you answering your own question? :p